# print out the on-screen-output from a python program to a file without writing them to a file inside the python program

Tags: python, linux

How to print out the on-screen-output from a python program to a file without writing them to a file inside the python program on Linux ?

I use:

my.py > my.log

but no my.log exist after running my.py, which works well.

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: If there is output when you run my.py without redirection, that is the correct way to send that output to a file.  Perhaps the Python file is writing to STDERR?  Try `my.py &> my.log`.

Comment: This seems unlikely to me.  `my.log` should exist (assuming you're using a standard `sh`-like shell.) although `my.log` may be empty if you're writing to `stderr` in python ...

Comment: @F.J -- but `my.log` should still *exist*.  It would just be *empty* in that scenario ...

Comment: If you leave the `> my.log` off does anything appear on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your program sends its output to the console, this should capture both the standard input and standard error streams to `my.log` in the `bash` shell:

```
$ my.py >my.log 2>&1
```

To keep the output visible you can use [`tee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee):

```
$ my.py 2>&1 | tee my.log
```